# How can use a ng-change function for three different fields in a same page which do not fall in cyclic call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have three angular-moment-datepicker fields , one date picker field , one month picker and one year picker field respectively in a same page as follows

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="BY DAY" ng-model="date" moment-picker="gDate" start-view="month" format="MM/DD/YYYY" today="true" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" change="getData('day')" />
<input class="form-control" placeholder="BY MONTH" ng-model="month" moment-picker="gMonth" format="MM/YYYY" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" change="getData('month')" />
<input class="form-control" placeholder="BY YEAR" ng-model="year" moment-picker="gYear" format="YYYY" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" change="getData('year')" />
```

and the angular function is

```
        $scope.getData = function (Level) {
            var dateRange = "";
            if (Level == 'day') {
                if ($scope.date != "") {
                    var Value = $scope.date;
                    var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
                    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    dateRange = new Date(localTime);
                }
                $scope.month = "";
                //$scope.gMonth = "";
                $scope.year = "";
                //$scope.gYear = "";
            } else if (Level == 'month') {
                var Value = $scope.month;
                var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
                localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                dateRange = new Date(localTime);
                //$scope.gYear = "";
                //$scope.gDate = "";
                $scope.date = "";
                $scope.year = "";
            } else {
                var Value = $scope.year;
                var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
                localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                dateRange = new Date(localTime);
                //$scope.gDate = "";
                //$scope.gMonth = "";
                $scope.date = "";
                $scope.month = "";
            }
            if (dateRange != "" || dateRange != undefined) {
                searchService.getDataFromDb(Level, dateRange).then(function (result) {
                //process result
                })
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is when I selected date, should clear month and year fields. But what happen is that the clearing for month and year in 'day' loop will trigger ng-change and then it will run getData('month') and getData('year') at same time so expected data is not getting. Also selected value is not displaying in the corresponding textfield

I tried the following function instead of getData() function in textfields

```
$scope.checkForDateType = function () {
    if ($scope.date != "") {
            $scope.getData('day');
    }
    if ($scope.month != "") {
            $scope.getData('month');
    }
    if ($scope.year != "") {
            $scope.getData('year');
    }
}
```

But the result is same..
Please help me to get correct data and displaying selected value in the corresponding text field

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
Set a global variable and assign the datetype and check it all section in the function.

```
$scope.setGlobal = function (from) {
    $scope.globelDateType = from;
}

$scope.getData = function (Level) {
    var dateRange = "";
    if ($scope.globelDateType == "") {
        $scope.setGlobal(Level);   //new change
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (Level == 'day') {
       if ($scope.date != "") {
           var Value = $scope.date;
            var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
            localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            dateRange = new Date(localTime);
       }else {
           $scope.setGlobal("");  //new change
           return false;
       }
        $scope.month = "";
        $scope.year = "";
    } else if (Level == 'month') {
        if ($scope.month == "") {
           $scope.setGlobal(""); //new change
           return false;
        }
        var Value = $scope.month;
        var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
        localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        dateRange = new Date(localTime);
        $scope.date = "";
        $scope.year = "";
     } else {
        if ($scope.year == "") {
           $scope.setGlobal("");    //new change
           return false;
        }
        var Value = $scope.year;
        var localTime = moment.utc(Value).toDate();
        localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        dateRange = new Date(localTime);
        $scope.date = "";
        $scope.month = "";
     }
     if (dateRange != "" || dateRange != undefined) {
         searchService.getDataFromDb(Level, dateRange).then(function (result) {
            //process result
            })
     }

     $scope.setGlobal(""); //new change
}
```

If any call back work, setting global variable is only through $scope.setGlobal() function. This global variable and ng-model value decides which loop should execute and corresponding loop execute and all other methods will result false condition.